# convert low hex values to their equivalent decimal values in Python

Tags: python, hex

If you look at [this chart](http://www.ascii-code.com/) you will see that the hex value of `02` has a decimal value of 2.  I am trying to convert a `byte`, which has the value `b'\x02'` into that decimal value, with the following

```
int(val, 16)
```

But I get the following:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\x02'
```

How can I fix this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a hex value. It's a `str` object. Use [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) to convert it to `int`:

```
>>> ord('\x02')
2
>>> ord(b'\x02')
2
```

You can convert it back to `str` using [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr):

```
>>> chr(2)
'\x02'
```

to convert it back to `bytes`, use `bytes`:

```
>>> bytes([2])
b'\x02'
```

Comment: Sorry, I must not have been clear enough.  It is a `byte` object so running this just gave me `int required`

Comment: @Startec, It would also work for `bytes` objects: `ord(b'\x02')` returns 2.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Now I really don't know which answer is better